# CQ5 - unable to edit inline <cq:text> tags inside dragable components

Tags: text, inline, edit, aem

I am trying to create a component that contains inside its body a [**< cq:text>**](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/howto/taglib.html) tag **(not the dragable component)** that I would like to modify its content according to specific cases, by clicking on it, and type in the content I want it to have (like the text drag able component).
I tried to implement a several solutions I found on the net (and also here) about the **inplaceEditing**, but none of theme was succeeded. Also - the documentation from Adobe I found on it was very poor, without any examples.

Does anyone succeed achieving that **without** using the component's dialog or placing a
**< cq:include path="par" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys"/>** to hold the text? And how?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Look over the OOTB text component /libs/foundation/components/text . It has cq:inplceEditing enabled by default. Drop that component inside parsys area.To check cq:inplceEditing do not double-click on the text component,In that case it will open the dialog. Just Select it and then click under it to edit.

Hope this will help.

Comment: That's not what I meant (see the edited version), but thanks anyway!